# Algolia: how to show video thumbnails as search results

Tags: wordpress, algolia

I would like to use "Search by Algolia" WP plugin to let my visitors search among videos. How can I have video thumbnails as search results, with the possibility for visitors to click on thumbnails to watch the videos (without having to be redirected to other pages first)?

Has anyone code snippets or advice on this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi there, do you use a custom field for the video? I suppose you want to embed videos from YouTube or Vimeo?

Comment: Also do you use a custom post type? An external plugin?